# Add Button with Image and Text in ToolbarItem SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want button exactly as in Reminders app in iOS
Below code note working, I also tried using label and system image name.

```
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        Text("New Reminder")
                    }
                })

            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any luck? I'm also trying to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom label style

```
struct VerticalLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            configuration.icon.font(.headline)
            configuration.title.font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can you use the custom style for your label

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
   Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
      .labelStyle(VerticalLabelStyle())
})
```

[image: icon with title underneath]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, the key thing was using `.buttonstyle(.plain)` and also embedding everything in a `HStack` with a `Spacer()` to push the button to the right.

[Text and Icon button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3U6r.png)

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    Text("Add Event")
                        .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded).bold())
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ViktorEvil's solution, this worked for me.  Primary difference is moving the Spacer() outside the button as when it was inside, it completely disappeared.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        HStack {
            Button {
                // action code goes here
                print("Pressed button")
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    Text("New Reminder")
                        .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded).bold())
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```